# apt-get install doesn't get the package

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, apt, packages

I've installed ubuntu server on a VirtualBox virtual machine and now I'm trying to follow a tutorial that says I need to install a package called `csh`. When I type this line

```
sudo apt-get install csh
```

I get "unable to locate package csh". This happens with all 4 other packages I tried to install. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps the VM can't reach the Internet. How do I check, or troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you contact anything on the internet (like ping google.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a brand new install?  You should probably run `apt-get update` first, then `apt-get install` stuff.

If `apt-get update` fails, then the chances are, that your network configuration isn't letting you out onto the internets.